# Javascript: quick string test

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to know how to test strings composed of certain string and characters. I've tested

- `/translate+x|y|z/i.test('translateX')` returns `true`
- `/translate+x|y|z/i.test('translate')` returns `false`
- `/translate+x|y|z/i.test('rotateX')` returns `false`

So with other words, I need to know if the string is `translateX` or `translateY` or `translateZ` but I am not sure if I have / don't have to escape the `+` there. Also please DO suggest a better all round, cross-browser solution that can be shorter / more precise.

Comment: What are trying to achieve? What are the requirements? `\+` matches a literal `+` and in your pattern, `+` is a quantifier allowing to match several `e` after `translat`.

Comment: I would assume that it's `/translate[xyz]?/i` what he means

Comment: Thanks for the input, so I basically want to know if the string is `translateX` or `translateY` or `translateZ` in a very short and efficient `.test()` call.

Comment: then `/^translate[XYZ]$/.test(text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I basically want to know if the string is `translateX` or `translateY` or `translateZ` in a very short and efficient `.test()` call.

You can use

```
/^translate[XYZ]$/
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pA1gV2/2).

The regex matches a string that is equal to `translateX`, `translateY` or `translateZ`.

- `^` - start of string
- `translate` - a literal character sequence
- `[XYZ]` - either `X`, `Y` or `Z` (`[ ... ]` a character class where the single characters alternatives are listed)
- `$` - end of string

**If you need to add multicharacter alternatives, use *alternation***:

```
/^translate(?:[XYZ]|3d)$/
           ^^^     ^^^^
```

This regex will match those 3 strings as above, or `translate3d`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for such a detailed answer/suggestion.

Comment: Glad it works for you. One note: if you need to make it case insensitive, add `/i` to the end: `/^translate[XYZ]$/i`.

Comment: Actually, how can I add 3d to the `[XYZ]` list?

Comment: Use alternation: `/^translate(?:[XYZ]|3d)$/`

Comment: Excellent, that worked perfect. I wish you were my friend forever :)